# RDLC including page gaps automatically, in my report

Tags: .net, rdlc

I an trying to print an RDLC report having two tablices which in normal looks like this [image: In normal circumstances] . In normal circumstances our report is more than two pages long, but sometimes the report behaves weird and automatically introduces a gap pushing the second tablix to the next page. In that case report looks like this [image]

Comment: facing a very rare case and need the reason to why it is happening ... how the code behind of rdlc decides the pagination etc and what is its impact in my case ... any help sooner would be appreciated.

Comment: @marr75 I read ur answer on another question where you mentioned "Your mileage may vary, and I find rdlc's add development and maintenance complexity, especially when your report has been designed as a server side report." were you talking of added complexity similar to this one?